# correlation matrix between cities

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the corr btw cities and and Rainfall. Note that 'city' is categorical, not numerical.
I wand to compare their rainfall.

How do I go about it? I haven't seen anything on here that talk about how to deal with duplicate cities with different data
like

```
    Date    Location    MinTemp MaxTemp Rainfall
12/1/2008   Albury     13.4     22.9    0.6
12/2/2008   Albury      7.4     25.1    0
12/3/2008   Albury      12.9    25.7    0
12/5/2008   Brisbane    20.5     29    9.6
12/6/2008   Brisbane    22.1    33.4    7.8
12/7/2008   Brisbane    22.6    33.4    12.4
12/8/2008   Brisbane    21.9    26.7    0
12/9/2008   Brisbane    19.5    27.6    0.2
12/10/2008  Brisbane    22.1    30.3    0.6
3/30/2011   Tuggeranong 9.8     25.2    0.4
3/31/2011   Tuggeranong 10.3    18.5    2.8
5/1/2011    Tuggeranong 5.5     20.8    0
5/2/2011    Tuggeranong 11      16.1    0
5/3/2011    Tuggeranong 7.3     17.5    0.6
8/29/2016   Woomera     15      22.9    0
8/30/2016   Woomera     12.5    22.1    12.8
8/31/2016   Woomera     8       20  0
9/1/2016    Woomera     11.6    21.4    0
9/2/2016    Woomera     11.2    19.6    0.3
9/3/2016    Woomera      7.1    20.4    0
9/4/2016    Woomera      6.5    18.6    0
9/5/2016    Woomera      7.3    21.5    0
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a correlation between a categorical variable and a numeric variable. What exactly do you expect to measure?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, if I understood you correctly (based on the title of OP), is:

**Step 1**

Preparing a dataset with `Locations` as columns and `Rainfall` as rows (note, you will lose information here up to a shortest rainfall series)

```
df2=df.groupby("Location")[["Location", "Rainfall"]].head(3) # head(3) is first 3 observations
df2.loc[:,"col"] = 4*["x1","x2","x3"] # 4 is number of unique cities
df3 = df2.pivot_table(index="col",columns="Location",values="Rainfall")
df3
Location    Albury  Brisbane    Tuggeranong Woomera
col             
x1          0.6      9.6         0.4          0.0
x2          0.0      7.8         2.8         12.8
x3          0.0      12.4        0.0          0.0
```

**Step 2**
Doing correlation matrix on the obtained dataset

```
df3.corr()

Location      Albury    Brisbane    Tuggeranong Woomera
Location                
Albury       1.000000   -0.124534   -0.381246   -0.500000
Brisbane    -0.124534   1.000000    -0.869799   -0.797017
Tuggeranong -0.381246   -0.869799   1.000000    0.991241
Woomera     -0.500000   -0.797017   0.991241    1.000000
```

An alternative, slightly more involved solution would be to keep the longest series and impute missing values with means or median.

But even though you will feed more data into your algo, it won't cure the main problem: your data seem to be misaligned. What I mean by this is that to do correlation analysis properly you should make it sure, that you compare comparable values, e.g. rainfall for summer with rainfall for summer for another city. To do analysis this way, you should make it sure you have equal amount of comparable rainfalls for each city: e.g. winter, spring, summer, autumn; or, January, February, ..., December.